# Update MySQL Column with WHERE condition

Tags: mysql

I need to change the information in a column to Degraded, where it is Feature Broken or Degradated.  Is this the correct line?

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET column = 'Degraded' 
WHERE column = 'Degradated' OR column= 'Feature Broken'
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Did you try it?

Comment: Do you really have column named `column`..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use an IN operator, to avoid the OR:

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = 'Degraded' WHERE columnname IN ('Degradated', 'Feature Broken');
```

Also, I would suggest running a SELECT first so you are somewhat aware of how many rows will be changed with your command.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

You could make it more concise (but it is *exactly* the same otherwise)

```
...
WHERE column IN ('Degradated','Feature Broken')
```